# checkbox from 2d array (ID, value) , $_POST can only transfer ID or value, but both needed --- what do?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out following problem, i got a 2D array:

```
$array=array(
array
(
    'customer_group_id'=>"0",
    'customer_group_code'=> "NOT LOGGED IN"
),

array
(
    'customer_group_id'=>"1",
    'customer_group_code'=> "General"
),
array
(
    'customer_group_id'=>"2",
    'customer_group_code'=> "Wholesale"
),
array
(
    'customer_group_id'=>"3",
    'customer_group_code'=> "Retailer"
),);
```

from that I create a checkbox which is part of a form:

```
    foreach ($array as $key => $arr)
{
    printf( '<input type="checkbox" name="grpname[]" value="%s_%s">%s<br />',$arr['customer_group_id'],$arr['customer_group_code'] ,$arr['customer_group_code'] );
}
```

With: `$_POST['grpname']` I create an regular array with the selected values, but id like to have a 2D array, ideally in the same pattern as posted in my first block of code.
I added `_%s`to the value of the checkbox so it combines the ID with the value separated by `_` in the hope i somehow could split them in two arrays that i would combine somehow, but so far I'm lost.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to transfer multiple values? It seems `customer_group_id` can perfectly act as a unique identifier. Meaning it would suffice to use it as the checkbox value. After submission, search in `$array` for those values to get the complete record.

Comment: Yeah sadly I need both values.

Comment: Are you sure you understood my comment? I did not want to imply that ultimately you won't be able to *get* both values. What I'm saying is that to reach that goal, you'll only need to pass the id.

Comment: Sorry I did press "Enter" to start a new line and my comment was posted, I already forgot about that as I was thinking about your answer :).
So i could use my generated $array full of IDs only, and then search for those IDs in the original array?

Comment: Yes, that would be my suggestion. I'll provide a simple answer as a starting point.